# Why this order is well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand why this order defined in Fulton's [algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) is indeed well-defined:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Why $u\in \mathcal{O_P}(X)$ (he is implicitly assuming this fact so that he can use the preposition 7)
2. Why $f/g, g/f\in \mathcal{O}_P(X)\implies \text{ord}_P(f)=\text{ord}_P(g)$?

Thanks

Comment: (2) mean that $f/g$ invertible in $\mathcal O_P(X)$ hence $\text{ord}_P(f/g)=0$.

Comment: @Hamou yes, it's true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is explained right before proposition 7 of the preceding section.

For your second question, $f/g\in \mathcal O_p(X)$ means that $\operatorname{ord}_P(f/g)=\operatorname{ord}_P(f)-\operatorname{ord}_P(g)\geq 0$. Likewise, $\operatorname{ord}_P(g)-\operatorname{ord}_P(f)\geq 0$.

Comment: To be self-contained: $\Omega$ is an $\mathcal{O}_P(X)$-module, generated by $dt$, so elements are precisely of the form $f \in \mathcal{O}_P(X)$ times $dt$